# File upload to S3 using form without action file in the form

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I'm trying to create a form with php to upload files to S3, the pages I have are as follow:

default.php:

```
<form method="post" class="form-group" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label>Upload file</label>
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" class="form-control">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit-App" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

dbupdate.php:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $bucketName = '*********';
   $IAM_KEY = '********************';
   $IAM_SECRET = '********************************';
   try {
       $s3 = S3Client::factory(
           array(
                'credentials' => array(
                'key' => $IAM_KEY,
                'secret' => $IAM_SECRET
            ),
            'version' => 'latest',
            'region'  => 'eu-west-1'
        )
    );
} catch (Exception $e) {

    die("Error: " . $e->getMessage());
}
$keyName = 'testfile/' . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]['name']);
try {
    // Uploaded:
    $file = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]['tmp_name'];
    $s3->putObject(
        array(
            'Bucket'=>$bucketName,
            'Key' =>  $keyName,
            'SourceFile' => $file,
            'StorageClass' => 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY'
        )
    );

   } catch (S3Exception $e) {
        die('Error:' . $e->getMessage());
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die('Error:' . $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

For some reason, this is not working, it creates the folder `testfile/` inside the target bucket but it doesn't upload the file. I tried to make a normal form with `action="dbupdate.php"` and remover the `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` and it works perfectly, but I need it to be the other way (without `action` file)

any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a condition to check file exists

```html
<form method="post" class="form-group" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label>Upload file</label>
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" class="form-control">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit-App" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>

<?php


if (isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_FILES["fileToUpload"]) &&  !empty($_FILES["fileToUpload"]['tmp_name'])) {

    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    use Aws\S3\S3Client;
    use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

    $bucketName = '*********';
    $IAM_KEY    = '********************';
    $IAM_SECRET = '********************************';
    try {
        $s3 = S3Client::factory(array(
            'credentials' => array(
                'key' => $IAM_KEY,
                'secret' => $IAM_SECRET
            ),
            'version' => 'latest',
            'region' => 'eu-west-1'
        ));
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        die("Error: " . $e->getMessage());
    }

    $keyName = 'testfile/' . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]['name']);

    try {
        // Uploaded:
        $file = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]['tmp_name'];
        $s3->putObject(array(
            'Bucket' => $bucketName,
            'Key' => $keyName,
            'SourceFile' => $file,
            'StorageClass' => 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY'
        ));
        
    }
    catch (S3Exception $e) {
        die('Error:' . $e->getMessage());
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        die('Error:' . $e->getMessage());
    }
}
?>
```